# Inequality and possible values

Tags: inequality

If ab=200, then find the number of possible values of a+b.

*a* and  *b* are real numbers.

Comment: Where is the *inequality*?

Comment: may be you are asking for positive integers $a$ and $b$

Comment: If you are seeking positive integers $a, b$, then look at the number of factors of $200$.  Now why would each factor correspond to a different value of $a+b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want the possible values of $a+\dfrac{200}a$.

Now if $a> 0$, by AM-GM, $a+\dfrac{200}a \ge 20\sqrt2$.
Multiplying by $-1$, we get $-a-\dfrac{200}a \le -20\sqrt2$.

So $a+b$ can take (and does take) all real values except those in $(-20\sqrt2, 20\sqrt2)$.  The number of values is thus not finite.